# android: how add edittext value when posting image to server

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

im new in android dev...
i find this code for upload image to server and its work perfect...
just i add editext in layout and i want post value of that edittext with image to server too
part of my code:

```
 URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
         conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
         conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
         conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
         dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

         while (bytesRead > 0) {
           dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
           bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);              
          }

         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

         // Responses from the server (code and message)
         int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
         //String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
         if(serverResponseCode == 200){
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
```

my edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="164dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="About Your picture"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
```

can anyone add example with my code how i get value in this editext and add it to form
for post both image and value of this edittext?

Comment: i find conn.setRequestProperty("firstName", "Stephen"); in this site - it is work for solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
conn.setRequestProperty("firstName", "Stephen");
```

u have to use

```
conn.setRequestProperty("firstName", urDetailEdtTxt.getText().toString());
```

for this kind of `post request` u need a **Key-Value** pair if the *key* is `firstName` then it will work other wise replace the *key* with correct one.